# BackboneJS click event not firing

Tags: backbone.js, youtube

I know this has been asked before but I couldn't find the right answer, even though it's pretty simple:

I have this in my HTML template:

```
<div id="vid"></div>
<button class="mdk-close">x</button>
```

and this in my View:

```
function (App, Backbone, ArtistVideos, Artistimg, Artistname) {

    var ArtistVideoPopup = App.module();

    ArtistVideoPopup.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'artistYoutubeVideo',
        events: {
            "click .mdk-close": "test"
        },
        test: function() {
            alert('dasdasas')
        },  
        beforeRender: function() {
            var artistimgCollection = new Artistimg.ArtistimgCollection();
            artistimgCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistImage', new Artistimg.View({collection: artistimgCollection}));
            artistimgCollection.fetch();

            var artistnameCollection = new Artistname.ArtistnameCollection();
            artistnameCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistName', new Artistname.View({collection: artistnameCollection}));
            artistnameCollection.fetch();

            var artistvideosModel = new ArtistVideos.ArtistVideosModel();
            artistvideosModel.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            artistvideosModel.video_youtube_id = this.video_youtube_id;
            artistvideosModel.fetch();
        },      

        afterRender: function() {

            $('ul.acmenu li a.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('ul.acmenu li a.artistVideos').addClass('selected');

            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = _.bind(function() {
              player = new YT.Player('vid', {
                height: '480',
                width: '853',
                videoId: this.video_youtube_id,
                events: {
                  onReady: onPlayerReady,
                  onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
                }
             })
            }, this);

            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }

            var done = false;
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                // if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                    // setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                    // done = true;
                // }
            }
            function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
            }


        },



    });

    return ArtistVideoPopup;
}
```

but the event is not firing at all. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sounds to me like you have some other JS errors that are preventing the browser from parsing this code. The code you posted here looks fine to me. Are you seeing any errors in your JS console?

Comment: @Lix no, there are no errors, which is what makes me wonder...

Comment: The code you have posted is 100% valid. The problem has to be with something else in your code.

Comment: @Lix OK! is it maybe because the button not is rendered by the view and just hardcoded in the html template?

Comment: for sure! The event will only be fired for elements that are associated with the specific view... You said that "I have this in my HTML template" so I assumed that the HTML is associated with the view...

Comment: @Lix OK! I edited my question, so please check it out...

Comment: Oh..so you're saying that you haven't explicitly rendered the template... However, you are able to see the HTML content, so it appears that the views render function is being called as part of the base backbone view class...

Comment: Could you try something else in the `test` function? Perhaps a `console.log` instead of an `alert`? I'm trying to rule out the possibility that you might have marked [this checkbox](http://i.imgur.com/SZCIAgB.png) at some stage.

Comment: This would prevent your page from generating any alert dialogs.

Comment: console.log returns nothing... :-/

Comment: Can you try removing the `bindAll` call? I'm kind of fishing right now... your code appears to be correct. There must be something else that is causing these problems...

Comment: Hmm I actually tried removing `bindAll` earlier, no luck... This is getting too weird and too strange...

Comment: OK Anyone??? This is driving me insane...

Comment: @muistooshort OK, I pasted my whole View into my question...thats all I can do - I hope this can help somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `events` in your view are bound only to elements inside the `view.el`

Comment: But how come that in another view I have, which is build the same way, I have added `events: {'click .somelink':'dostuff'}, dostuff:function(){do stuff}` and that works well? In that view i also have `template: 'some_template` and in the html template there is basic HTML???